# How to Define API Key in Header Not in Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi, api-key

I have been using my API key as a query parameter. But I don't like how my API key stays remembered in the web browser. So, I want to have it passed in the header, not as a query parameter. Below is my yaml file, which I got from Cloud Endpoints documentations

```
security:
  - api_key: []

securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: key
    in: query
```

When I change `in: query` to `in: header` , it doesn't seem to do the job. Because, I still can call my API with the API key as a query parameter. Also, when I check Developer Portal, Try This API for all the endpoints that use the API key are disabled. I can't think of any other way than changing `in: query` to `in: header` , which doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? And, how can I specify API Key in the header?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. It's not possible with Cloud Endpoints. That's all.